# Using wheels with fewer holes

Tags: ford, wheels, lug-nut

I have a ford E350 van with 8-hole (8-lug?) wheels. On short notice I need to find some steel rims on which I can travel at a short distance (50 meters) at a low speed (< 10 Km/h).

It is difficult to find compatible steel wheels here, but I have been told I can use any wheels where "at least 2 of the holes line up".

I can't see how this could work though: if there aren't at least 8 holes which line up with the studs, how could I mount such a wheel? The missing holes would block the studs, preventing the wheels from being mounted.

Am I missing something stupid here?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I would bet there are a ton of these wheels if you care to look for them. F250 trucks came with the same wheels as your van. Call up the wrecking yard and I'm sure they'll easily be able to find you some.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - unfortunately I'm in a country with plenty of F-150s but I've never seen an F-250 and I don't think they sell them here. In any case, it seems like the F-250 was always sold with [an 8x170 pattern](https://www.wheel-size.com/size/ford/f-250/2010/), but I believe my van has an [8x165 pattern](https://www.wheel-size.com/size/ford/e-350-van/2008/)... or are these compatible? Edit: seems like F250 used it for 1998 and earlier.

Comment: What year is your E350?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - it's a 2008.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not.

Only use correct rims for the vehicle, you can change rim diameter and offset within limits as it change the handling characteristics, but the hole pattern should match properly for safety.

If the wheel is only held on by two studs/nuts then cornering forces can cause them to fail catastrophically or the wheel to fail.

Comment: I'm only driving a total of 50 meters at ~5 km/h on flat ground w/o any other vehicles, so the usual safety rules can be relaxed here.

Comment: @BeeOnRope and you are the safety expert? What happens if a kid makes a mistake and the wheel fails on emergency braking?

Comment: No I am not a safety expert, but it doesn't take any special training to know that the safety requirements of driving a vehicle on public roads at high speeds are *wildly different* than driving it at crawling speeds ~50 meters in a straight line on private property in a controlled environment with professionals at the wheel and no "kids" in sight. The world isn't black and white.